# Como fazer leituras de Json com varias listas(DELPHI)?

Tags: android, json, delphi, firemonkey

Estou usando os exemplos do XSUPEROBJET para fazer a leitura do Json abaixo, porém os exemplos usam estruturas simples de Json, e que funcionam, mas quando tento ler as estrututas com varias listas não funcionam.

Não sei o que estou fazendo de errado.

Meu problema é: **ler estes registros**

```
    {
     "dadospedido":
     {
     "pedido":
       [
       {
         "ID":"19",
         "ID_EMPRESA":"107868",
         "DATA":"29/06/17",
         "ID_CLIENTE":"5",
         "ID_PAGTO":"29",
         "CODCLIENTE":"7",
         "HORA":"17:07:35",
         "CODVENDEDOR":"2",
         "CONLUIU":"C",
         "OBS":"Legal",
         "TOTAL":"60"
       }
       ],
     "itens":
       [
       {
         "ID":"65",
         "ID_PEDIDO":"19",
         "ID_EMPRESA":"107868",
         "ID_PRODUTO":"441200",
         "CODIGOPRODUTO":"506",
         "QTD":"1",
         "UNITARIO":"60",
         "UNIDADE":"UN",
         "VTOTAL":"60",
         "DESCRICAO":"Enviar em uma caixa com vários pra economizar"
       }
       ],
     "formapagto":
       [
       {
         "ID":"103",
         "ID_PEDIDO":"19",
         "ID_EMPRESA":"107868",
         "FORMA":"Boleto",
         "VENCIMENTO":"22/09/17",
         "VALOR":"10",
         "NOMEBANCO":"",
         "NOMECHEQUE":"",
         "NUMBANCO":"",
         "AGENCIA":"",
         "NUMCONTA":"",
         "NUMCHEQUE":"",
         "DATAATU":"30/12/99",
         "PARCELA":"1 - 6"
       },
       {
         "ID":"104",
         "ID_PEDIDO":"19",
         "ID_EMPRESA":"107868",
         "FORMA":"Boleto",
         "VENCIMENTO":"29/09/17",
         "VALOR":"10",
         "NOMEBANCO":"",
         "NOMECHEQUE":"",
         "NUMBANCO":"",
         "AGENCIA":"",
         "NUMCONTA":"",
         "NUMCHEQUE":"",
         "DATAATU":"30/12/99",
         "PARCELA":"2 - 6"
       },
       {
         "ID":"105",
         "ID_PEDIDO":"19",
         "ID_EMPRESA":"107868",
         "FORMA":"Boleto",
         "VENCIMENTO":"06/10/17",
         "VALOR":"10",
         "NOMEBANCO":"",
         "NOMECHEQUE":"",
         "NUMBANCO":"",
         "AGENCIA":"",
         "NUMCONTA":"",
         "NUMCHEQUE":"",
         "DATAATU":"30/12/99",
         "PARCELA":"3 - 6"
       },
       {
         "ID":"106",
         "ID_PEDIDO":"19",
         "ID_EMPRESA":"107868",
         "FORMA":"Boleto",
         "VENCIMENTO":"13/10/17",
         "VALOR":"10",
         "NOMEBANCO":"",
         "NOMECHEQUE":"",
         "NUMBANCO":"",
         "AGENCIA":"",
         "NUMCONTA":"",
         "NUMCHEQUE":"",
         "DATAATU":"30/12/99",
         "PARCELA":"4 - 6"
       },
       {
         "ID":"107",
         "ID_PEDIDO":"19",
         "ID_EMPRESA":"107868",
         "FORMA":"Boleto",
         "VENCIMENTO":"20/10/17",
         "VALOR":"10",
         "NOMEBANCO":"",
         "NOMECHEQUE":"",
         "NUMBANCO":"",
         "AGENCIA":"",
         "NUMCONTA":"",
         "NUMCHEQUE":"",
         "DATAATU":"30/12/99",
         "PARCELA":"5 - 6"
       },
       {
         "ID":"108",
         "ID_PEDIDO":"19",
         "ID_EMPRESA":"107868",
         "FORMA":"Boleto",
         "VENCIMENTO":"27/10/17",
         "VALOR":"10",
         "NOMEBANCO":"",
         "NOMECHEQUE":"",
         "NUMBANCO":"",
         "AGENCIA":"",
         "NUMCONTA":"",
         "NUMCHEQUE":"",
         "DATAATU":"30/12/99",
         "PARCELA":"6 - 6"
       }
       ]
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar as classes do System.JSON

Tens aqui exemplo que faz parse desse teu JSON para ir buscar os ID's 
(Pode haver modo mais directo mas já tens algo para começar)

```
procedure ParseJSON(JSONText:String);
var
  js:TJSONObject;
  jDadosPedido:TJSONObject;
  jFormapagto:TJSONObject;
  IDFormapagto:string;
  jArrFormapagto:TJSONArray;
  iter:integer;
begin
  js:=TJSONObject(TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSONText));
  if js<>nil then
  begin
    jDadosPedido:=TJSONObject(js.Values['dadospedido']);
    if jDadosPedido<>nil then
    begin
      jArrFormapagto:=TJSONArray(jDadosPedido.Values['formapagto']);
      for iter := 0 to jArrFormapagto.Count-1 do
      begin
        jFormapagto:=TJSONObject(jArrFormapagto.Items[iter]);
        IDFormapagto:=jFormapagto.Values['ID'].Value;
      end;

    end;
    js:=nil;
  end;
end;
```